# How to stop Get-Content -wait after I find a particular line in the text file using powershell? Exit a pipeline on demand

Tags: powershell, pipeline, break, powershell-5.0

I am using this below script in Powershell (Version is 5.1):

```
Get-Content -Path path\to\text\file\to\be\read.txt -Wait
```

Now this continues to read even after the file is getting no update.
How can I stop after I find particular line in the text file?
Is there any other way to stop this on condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the output and use foreach to check each line, if the line equals a certain string you can use `break` to stop the command:

```
Get-Content path\to\text\file\to\be\read.txt -wait | % {$_ ; if($_ -eq "yourkeyword") {break}}
```

For example, if you run the command above and do the following in another shell:

```
"yourkeyword" | Out-File path\to\text\file\to\be\read.txt -Append
```

The `Get-Content` displays the new line and stops.

---

**Explanation:**

`| %` - foreach line that is in the file or gets added to the file while the function runs

`$_;` - first write out the line of the foreach then do another command

`if($_ -eq "yourkeyword") {break}` - if the line of the foreach is equal to the keyword/line you want, stop the `Get-Content`

Answer (score 10):

**tl;dr**

```sh
do {
  Get-Content -Path path\to\text\file\to\be\read.txt -Wait | ForEach-Object {
    # Pass the input line through.
    $_
    # Exit once the string of interest is found.
    if ($_ -match 'patternOfInterest') { break } 
  }
} while ($false) # dummy loop so that `break` can be used.

# NOTE: Without the dummy `do` loop, this code would not be reached.
'Line of interest found.'
```

Note that the [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) performs *substring* matching using *regexes* ([`about_Regular_Expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)).

Read on for why the dummy `do` loop is needed.

---

[Paxz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51981203/45375) is on the right track, but **it tries to use `break` (in isolation) to *exit the pipeline*, which (typically) *terminates the whole script*** (if you submit the pipeline as a single command interactively, you may not notice).

**`break` / `continue` are designed to exit / continue *loops* (`for`, `foreach`, `do`, `while`, and `switch` statements<sup>[1]</sup>), not *pipelines***.

**As of PowerShell [Core] 7.2.2, *there is no direct way to exit a pipeline prematurely***, though adding this feature is the subject of [this long-standing feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3821); currently, only direct use of `Select-Object` with `-First` can exit a pipeline prematurely, through use of non-public exception; while `return` can be used in a `ForEach-Object` script block, it only exits the current script-block invocation while continuing to process additional pipeline input.

**If you use `break` or `continue`, PowerShell will look for *any* enclosing loop and *if there is none*, the *script as a whole* exits.**

However, **if you wrap a *dummy* loop around your pipeline**<sup>[2]</sup>, as shown above - whose sole purpose is to provide something for `break` to break out of - **execution *continues*, as (usually) desired**.

**Caveat**:

**`break` / `continue` (and `throw`) have an *important side effect***: they **do not give the other commands participating in the pipeline a chance to exit *normally***; that is, their `end` blocks / `EndProcessing()` methods are *not* called, which can be problematic in two respects:

- Cmdlets that need to clean up (dispose of) temporarily held resources *do not get to clean up*.

  - Note that, regrettably, this inability to clean up also applies to use of `Select-Object -First` with advanced PowerShell functions/scripts (but not with (binary) cmdlets, which can ensure cleanup by implementing the [`System.IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IDisposable) interface), as discussed in [GitHub issue #7930](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7930); [GitHub PR #9900](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/9900) aims to address that introducing a dedicated `cleanup` block.
- *Aggregating* cmdlets - those that of necessity collect *all* input before being able to produce output - *never get to produce output*; here's a simple example:

```sh
PS> do { 5..1 | % { $_; if ($_ -eq 3) { break } } | Sort-Object } while ($false)
# !! NO OUTPUT, because Sort-Object's EndProcessing() method was never called.
```

---

<sup>[1] When you examine a *single* value with a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) statement, `break` exits the statement, as you would expect. If an *array* (a collection) of values is being processed, `break` too exits the statement immediately, *without processing further elements in the array*; `continue`, by contrast, continues processing with the next element.</sup>

<sup>[2] Another option is to use `throw` to generate a script-terminating error that you catch by enclosing the pipeline in a [`try` / `catch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally), as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60330780/45375).  However, this has the side effect of recording an entry in the automatic `$Error` collection, even though *conceptually* no actual error occurred.</sup>

Comment: Per your comment about Select-Object if all you need is to match a string and exit this is pretty nice `gc file -wait | ? { $_ -match "Pattern" } | Select -First 1`

Comment: Good point, @RiverHeart - if none of the _other_ lines are to be passed through, that is the simplest solution.