# "Break" causes a PowerShell script to fail

Tags: powershell, crash, break

```
(GSV).Name|%{If($_ -like "*net*"){ $_ ; Break }};Pause
```

When I run the above line from a PowerShell window, "**Netlogon**" will be output. 
When I run a PS1 file that contains the same line, a PowerShell window will appear and then disappear immediately, and nothing will be output. 
What is wrong with that line?

Comment: Mathias' answer explains the problem well and offers the best solution for your specific use case. Unfortunately, as of PowerShell 7.2.2 there still is no _general_ mechanism for _exiting a pipeline on demand_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60341948/45375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the `about_Break` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-7.2#do-not-use-break-outside-of-a-loop-switch-or-trap):

> ### Do not use break outside of a loop, `switch`, or `trap`
>
> When `break` is used outside of a construct that directly supports it
> (loops, `switch`, `trap`), PowerShell looks up the call stack for an
> enclosing construct. If it can't find an enclosing construct, the
> current runspace is quietly terminated.
>
> This means that functions and scripts that inadvertently use a break
> outside of an enclosing construct that supports it can inadvertently
> terminate their callers.
>
> **Using break inside a pipeline break, such as a `ForEach-Object` script block, not only exits the pipeline, it potentially terminates
> the entire runspace.**

Rewrite your script to use `Where-Object` to filter the input, then use `Select-Object -First 1` to terminate the pipeline once an object matches the filter:

```
(GSV).Name |Where-Object { $_ -like "*net*" } |Select-Object -First 1; Pause
```

In this particular case you can also use `Get-Service`'s filtering capabilities to narrow the initial query to only matching services, voiding the need for `Where-Object` all together:

```
Get-Service -Name *net* |Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1
```